# Удаление из B-дерева

Tags: c, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Не могу разобраться с алгоритмом удаления из `В-дерева`. В Вирте очень размыто описано удаление второго случая (не листового).

Возникает проблема с интерпретацией шагов алгоритма. Не понятно,какие действия необходимо сделать, то есть , что нужно увидеть в построенном дереве, чтобы сделать то или иное действие.

Может кто-нибудь написать алгоритм удаления из `B-дерева` ?

Comment: Почитайте Кормена "Алгоритмы"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node* findMinNode(node* p) {
    while (p->left != NULL) p = p->left;
    return p;
}

node* DeleteNode(node *root, node * delnode)
{
    if (root == NULL) return root;

    else if (root->value > delnode->value) root->left = DeleteNode(root->left, delnode);

    else if (root->value < delnode->value)  root->right = DeleteNode(root->right, delnode);
    else {
        // у  узла нет дочерних узлов
        // просто удаляем этот узел
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        {
            delete root;
            root = NULL;

        }

        // если есть один дочерний 
        // меняем на него 
        else if (root->left == NULL) {
            node *temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL) {
            node *temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            delete temp;
        }

        //если  удаляемый элемент имеет двух потомков
        //то нужно заменить его минимальным элементом из правого поддерева
        // и рекурсивно удалить минимальный элемент из правого поддерева
        else {
            node *temp = findMinNode(root->right);
            root->value = temp->value;
            root->right = DeleteNode(root->right, temp);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```